# Configuring SSL on Tomcat | Getting blank file

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I am generating my certificate using

> keytool -genkey -alias xyz -keyalg RSA -keystore xyz1

and have imported it to

```
  <Connector port="8443"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
    maxThreads="25" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="/Users/xyz/keytool/xyz1" keystorePass="HelloHello"/>
```

As per catalina logs, tomcat has been started successfully

> Oct 19, 2015 7:52:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO:
>   Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]

Now when I try to access my site page on HTTPS localhost:8443, a 7 byte blank file is downloaded, which contains some special character.

No errors appears on tomcat logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see my working ssl configuration:

```
    <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="conf/tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="*********"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

The keystore file is stored in a folder relative to the CATALINA_HOME parameter.
maybe there is an issue with the path?

try to put it relative to the tomcat root folder.

Another thing to check:
have you wrote https://localhost:8443/[your_war_path] in the browser?

EDIT:
another thing, check in the `web.xml` that you are sending data as confedential
for example:

```
 <security-constraint>
    <display-name>Unsecured</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Unsecured area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/login.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/passwordReset.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/public/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: hmmm I tried both the options, moved keystore file to tomcat directory, Also tried to access multiple url. Still if I tried to access same page via https a blank file gets downloaded. I have tried to put wrong path as well so that I can check the behavior of tomcat. In case it is not able to find the keystore file or invalid password it reports error which is not coming in my case.

Comment: try to clean all the tomcat temp files and the browsers cache & redploy war

Comment: tried same but still no luck, tried private window after clearing cache but still same behavior :( Just adding server info if it helps. Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
Server built:   Sep 26 2014 12:08:24
Server number:  7.0.56.0
OS Name:        Mac OS X
OS Version:     10.11
Architecture:   x86_64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_79-b15
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation

Comment: @tarunkumar please check my edit - does it solves your issue?

Comment: yes it did work .After adding security constrain on site it starts working without issue. Thanks a lot.